# Compression not working for journald log files

Tags: systemd, btrfs, compression, systemd-journald

So basically BTRFS transparent compression (zstd:0) isn't working for the log files under `/var/log/journal`. I don't understand this issue because manually compressing the files (zstd file) gives a significant difference in size, but compsize reports them 100% as uncompressed. The compression works fine for other partitions.

fstab

```
/dev/mapper/vg_1-lv_varlog /var/log        btrfs   compress-force=zstd,relatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0       0
```

compsize

```
Processed 21 files, 28 regular extents (28 refs), 0 inline.
Type       Perc     Disk Usage   Uncompressed Referenced
TOTAL      100%      1.0G         1.0G         1.0G
none       100%      1.0G         1.0G         1.0G
```

Examples files

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  72M Apr  3 07:32 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-00000000000c94d0-0005a2528ac7d3c7.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  72M Apr  3 19:09 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-00000000000de606-0005a25c3fec3527.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  72M Apr  4 06:45 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-00000000000f3745-0005a265fa4a95e6.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  72M Apr  4 18:20 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-000000000010887c-0005a26fb371f920.journal
```

Compression ratio example

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  72M Apr  8 06:55 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-00000000001c6a81-0005a2b9d9cd6e8f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 9.2M Apr  8 06:55 system@0a8678d3dc704a8c898bb86a8a8bc4bd-00000000001c6a81-0005a2b9d9cd6e8f.journal.zst
```

It even seems that journald is not even performing compression, or am I missing something?

Any advice on this?

Comment: What does `btrfs property get /var/log` and `btrfs property get /var/log/journal/system@uuid.journal` show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The first command: `ro=false
label=`, the second didn't output anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `/var/log/journal` folder is set as NOCOW (`+C`), which also disables the compression functionality in BTRFS. You can check it with the command `lsattr /var/log`.

Since the developers probably enabled it for a good reason, it's best to leave it as it is, especially since SUSE also applies that flag to that (and the whole /var) folder.

See my comment below for the specific details of the `+C` flag.

Comment: You should really add this information to your original question.

Comment: If you set the directory to what you want, do you get the compression you are seeking?  Is there a reason that directory was set to NOCOW?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have to disagree because this is the reason for my issue. Since the `+C` flag is set, BTRFS can't do its Copy-On-Write (read: compression) magic. journald automatically sets the folder as NOCOW, probably because of its very high write activity, which would have a negative effect on the performance of the BTRFS filesystem.

Comment: Good points. They helped me understand that this is an answer, not an elaboration of the question. Perhaps you could further explain your answer so future readers won't need to read the comments here.

Comment: Since `systemd` version 246 the journal is compressed by default. So file system compression would only waste CPU because more compression is not possible. Whether anybody would want to disable compression in `systemd-journald` and have the file system do it I don't know. Don't see an immediate use case for that.